Deployment of Tabular Model Fails in Visual Studio 2022
When I try deploying my tabular model on visual studio 2022, it shows validating credentials and then DEPLOY FAILED with no error message of what made the deployment failed. How do I fix this please.

I have ensured that your tabular model is compatible with the version of SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) that you are deploying to.
I have also ensured that I have the latest updates for Visual Studio 2022 and SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT).
I have also try rebuilding my solution in Visual Studio before deploying it again.
I have double-checked the server name and connection settings in my deployment configuration, I also made sure that the server is reachable and that the database you're deploying to exists.


Open the Event Viewer on your machine and check under "Windows Logs" -> "Application" for any SSAS-related error logs around the time of the deployment.

Have you or anyone else ever been able to deploy to this server or any other server? Wondering if this is one-time-only setup or something in the model. You could try a simple model with one table of hard-coded data to rule out data issues. Not sure how you get a real error message. I would also make sure you are using the full server address (server_name.your_domain.com) and not just server_name.
